# Android studio Emulator - Inquiring

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, haxm

I've installed all necessary components recommend by android studio except Intel HAXM.

Q1: is it necessary to install Intel HAXM to run android emulator?

Q2: what other free alternative of android studio emulator can run flutter app

I've tried installing Intel HAXM and the installation didn't complete because it's not satisfied with the requirements... (Is there any way I can install it?)

All I just wanted is to run my flutter app on an emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel HAXM is deprecated, don't waste time on it ;)
https://www.phoronix.com/news/Intel-Discontinues-HAXM

Personally i develop without anything. Just the default Android studio emulator / Xcode simulator and real devices.

Comment: My question is = is it compulsory to install HAXM to run emulator?

Comment: @devfreeguy Not at all :)

Comment: Alright Thanks dev